# libGDX ObjectOutputStream write fails with FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to save my settings in my Libgdx game with an `ObjectOutputStream`.  This works on the desktop.
But when I run the android application it crashes because:

> 02-19 12:36:33.500: W/System.err(20329): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /save.data: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

How i can save it to the android package in the assets folder?

My code is:

```
public void saveSettingsOut(){
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data/save.set"));
        out.writeObject(settingsMap);
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please don't suggest I use preferences, as I want that the data to be encoded.

Or is there maybe a better way to do this?  I want to save two hashmaps one with integers and one with booleans.

Comment: Please include the full error you see on the crash.  What is "it" in "it didn't exist"?

Comment: 02-19 12:36:33.500: W/System.err(20329): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /save.data: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) ... like i say no file exist....

Answer (score 0):

The "data" directory doesn't exist in the working directory of your app when running on Android.  The filesystem layout is very different in desktop and Android (and iOS and GWT) builds of Libgdx apps.  You should use the Libgdx APIs to get at the right part of the storage system.  See the Libgdx local file handling matrix: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#file-storage-types

You want the Libgdx "local" file storage, so try using:

```
new FileOutputStream(Gdx.files.local("save.set"))
```